# Why is my predicted vs observed plot worse for training than validation. Running an overfitted GBM on a binomial outcome

Tags: binomial-distribution, overfitting, bernoulli-distribution, boosting, h2o

I have a binomial outcome that I am trying to predict using a gbm in h2o.

I have set quite a low min_rows value for each node and it appears to be overfitting.  See plots below.

[image]

When I group the results into percentiles and plot Observed vs Predicted I get good results for Validation but Training shows a higher proportion of observed outcomes in the upper percentiles and lower observed outcomes in the lower percentiles.  See images below.

[image: Training]

I would have thought training would have predicted more accurately and the Validation and Hold Out plots would have been more inaccurate.  Is this the expected result and why does it occur?

**EDIT:**  Additional Imformation

I ran a grid search first which produced nearly 200 different models with a range of different settings. The "best" model with the training AUC of 0.8 and slightly higher validation AUC had a low lower min_rows (64). Allowing smaller nodes in the trees. The model with training AUC of 0.73 had min_rows of 4096.

I used the stopping Metric Logloss with 5 rounds and tolerance 0.001.

I'm still confused why the model with the better training AUC shows observed higher than predicted in the upper percentiles.  Here's the same PVO plot for the Hold Out dataset. [image: HoldOut]

Comment: What loss function are you minimizing, log-loss?

Comment: Yes Bernoulli Distribution type minimising logloss with a tolerance of 0.001

Answer (score 1):

None of your scoring history plots demonstrate overfitting.  An overfit model will show validation error decreasing to a certain point and then it starts to increase again -- the inflection point is where your model starts to overfit.  The validation error in all of your graphs is flat after a certain number of trees.

Here is a plot (Figure 7.1) from [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www.web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) that shows the equivalent of what the scoring history of an overfit model looks like (notice how test set error increases after a certain point).  Your validation error flattens out, so although you could stop training your model earlier than you did, I wouldn't look at that plot and think that the model is overfit.

[image]

I am not sure I understand what your concern is with the second plot of observed vs predicted on your training set.  Maybe it would make more sense if I saw the validation or test set plots as well, to provide some more context.  Are you using early stopping in your H2O model?  If so, then I'd compare against a new set set instead of the validation set (since the validation set would have already been used to tune the model).

Comment: Hi.  Here's an image of my Predicted vs Observed of the Hold Out dataset for comparison.  http://imgur.com/a/k0t4k  As you can see the match is much closer within each percentile.  With an AUC or 0.8 for training and only 0.71 for Validation and Hold out is the model really representative of the broader population?

Comment: Also to further clarify I have split the population of around 1 million records into training 50%, Validation 25% and Hold Out (test) 25%.  I use the logloss stopping criteria with 5 stopping rounds with a tolerance 0.001.  The model only takes a few minutes to run.  I guess I don't understand the impact of running for longer.  If the training AUC and Logloss continue to improve but the Validation flattens out isn't the model  created based on the training dataset getting further away from a generalised model that is appropriate for validation and hold out as well?

Comment: Another way to put it I guess is provided there's no overfitting (as per the definition you've provided) Is a model that shows the following Training AUC (0.8) Validation AUC (0.71) and Hold Out AUC (0.71) any better (or worse) than a model that shows Training AUC (0.73) Validation AUC (0.71) and Hold Out (0.71).  I do have a model that shows the second set of AUC values and the Predicted vs Observed for training appears more accurate.  But I'm trying to understand why.  http://imgur.com/a/zgh2r  Thanks so much for your help

Comment: There is nothing wrong with running the model longer if it doesn't overfit, other than it produces a model with more trees (which means it takes slightly longer to generate predictions).  If you want to stop earlier, set stopping_rounds = 3 or stopping_tolerance to >0.001.

Comment: I don't think there are any generalizations that you can make about whether the 0.8 training AUC model is better/worse than 0.73 training AUC model, given that the valid/hold-out AUCs are exactly the same for both models. I also think that if you are using the same algorithm for both models, such a discrepancy between training error of two models is unlikely to happen in practice.  If you saw a discrepancy like that, I'd turn to cross-validation to get a better estimate of generalization performance.

Comment: Sorry I should point out that I ran grid search first which produced nearly 200 different models with a range of different settings.  The "best" model with the training AUC of 0.8 and slightly higher validation AUC had a low lower min_rows (64).  Allowing smaller nodes in the trees.  The model with training AUC of 0.73 had min_rows of 4096.  So I kind of get why there's a difference in training AUC for the two models.  But back to my original question I'm still confused why the model with the better training AUC shows observed higher than predicted in the upper percentiles.